# Every character in TextBox in different color in vba excel

Tags: vba, excel, textbox

I'm looking for a way to display every letter in a *TextBox* within a *UserForm* in different colors using VBA. For example first character red,second blue,third... . Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not possible using *TextBox Control*.
If you are using *Excel 2010* or higher however, you can use *InkEdit Control*.
It is an additional control under *Tools > Additional Controls (Excel VBE)*.

[image]

Once you've added it, it will be available in your *Toolbox* as seen below.

[image]

You can then use it as another *Control* in your *UserForm*.
To know more about what you can do with an *InkEdit Control*, check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms698514(v=vs.85).aspx).
Btw, here is a sample code which colors the entry(per Char) based on its position as you type.

```
Private Sub InkEdit1_Change()

Dim i As Long

If Me.InkEdit1.Text <> "" Then
    For i = 1 To Len(Me.InkEdit1.Text)
        Me.InkEdit1.SelStart = i - 1 '~~> identifies the start of selection
        Me.InkEdit1.SelLength = 1 '~~> identifies the length of selection
        Select Case i
        Case 1: Me.InkEdit1.SelColor = RGB(255, 0, 0) '~~> colors 1st char Red
        Case 2: Me.InkEdit1.SelColor = RGB(0, 255, 0) '~~> colors 2nd char Green
        Case 3: Me.InkEdit1.SelColor = RGB(0, 0, 255) '~~> colors 3rd char Blue
        Case 4: Me.InkEdit1.SelColor = RGB(255, 255, 0) '~~> colors 4th char Yellow
        Case 5: Me.InkEdit1.SelColor = RGB(255, 0, 255) '~~> colors 5th char Indigo
        End Select
        Me.InkEdit1.SelStart = i '~~> this puts the cursor to end
    Next
End If

End Sub
```

For the above sample, I limit the number of characters entered in the control to 5.
*InkEdit* both accepts *RGB* and *Color Index* but I'm comfortable in using *RGB*.
Your question is lacking details so I cannot provide more; just hopes that this helps you a bit.
If ever, your version of Excel is not 2010, I think there's an equivalent control for lower versions as well.

**Result:**
[image]

Comment: @pnuts haha actually the first time I wrote the code I followed that, but the RGB sequence seems nice. :D

Comment: @pnuts There's no better way I think. Plus a bonus in showing how to convert from RGB equivalent of HEX. :D

Comment: @pnuts nah, I've seen worst :D