# Using InkPicture to add a signature to an Excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using the method I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48641960/userform-vba-inkpicture-input-into-sheet-specific-cell-as-image-user-signature).

The issue arises on `Set objInk = Me.SignPicture`.

I get

> 438 error Object doesn't support this property or method

The InkPicture control is named correctly (SignPicture), intellisense allows for the .Object.

```vb
Private Sub Use_Click()

'dim object type and byte array to save from binary
Dim objInk As MSINKAUTLib.InkPicture
Dim bytArr() As Byte
Dim File1 As String

'get temp file path as $user\Temp\[file name]
FilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\" & "Signature.png"

' set objInk as image/strokes of InkPicture control form object
Set objInk = Me.SignPicture

'if object is not empty
If objInk.Ink.Strokes.Count > 0 Then
    'get bytes from object save
    bytArr = objInk.Ink.Save(2)
    'create file for output
    Open FilePath For Binary As #1
    'output/write bytArr into #1/created (empty)file
    Put #1, , bytArr
    Close #1
End If

'set public File as file path to be used later on main sub
Signature.File = FilePath

Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you have you added Object, it's not in the code you link to? If you remove that the image will be saved to the temporary folder.

Comment: *Facepalm* sorry, yes I added that to try get around the original error, which i now see isn't where I thought it was. Its the second last line, Signature,File = FilePath that gives a error 424 "Object Required. So I made an error trying to fix an error.    So, removing the .Object, I'm back to the original Object required Error.

Comment: What is `Signature` supposed to be?

Comment: That's the issue, it isn't referenced anywhere else in his code. I removed it, making it File = FilePath and it works. Strangely, since removing it, the InkPicture control in the Userform now resizes it self to a perfect square everytime it loads now... It's the most bizarre things I've ever seen

Comment: Ok, so I fixed the magically resizing InkPicture control by adding the following to the Userform code..  Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
   With SignPicture
      .Width = 548
      .Height = 105
   End With
End Sub

Comment: Welcome to SO! As you can see, there are some items to improve in your original question. Rather than keep this information at the comments, please edit your question. The idea of comments is not to keep a chat between users but improve the question in order to be replied or solved.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so got it fixed, for anyone with similar issues, here's the working code.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
With SignPicture
  .Width = 548
  .Height = 105
End With
End Sub


Private Sub Use_Click()

'dim object type and byte array to save from binary
Dim objInk As MSINKAUTLib.InkPicture
Dim bytArr() As Byte
Dim File1 As String


'get temp file path as $user\Temp\[file name]
FilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\" & "Signature.png"

' set objInk as image/strokes of InkPicture control form object
Set objInk = Me.SignPicture

'if object is not empty
If objInk.Ink.Strokes.Count > 0 Then
    'get bytes from object save
    bytArr = objInk.Ink.Save(2)
    'create file for output
    Open FilePath For Binary As #1
    'output/write bytArr into #1/created (empty)file
    Put #1, , bytArr
    Close #1
End If

'set public File as file path to be used later on main sub
File = FilePath

Unload Me
End Sub
```